# Change of index key columns order affects performance

Tags: sql-server, profiler, nonclustered-index, database-tuning-advisor

I have the following table in my database:

```
create table [dbo].[tb_StatusLog](
[RequestID] [int] not null,
[statusID] [int] not null,
[startTime] [datetime] not null,
[endTime] [datetime] null,
)
```

with the following non-clustered index

```
create nonclusteredindex [index1] on [dbo].[tb_StatusLog]
(
requestID asc, 
statusID asc
)
include ([startTime])
```

and the following table-valued function `fn_getTable`

```
select requestID, max(startTime)
from tb_StatusLog
where statusID=2
group by requestID, statusID
```

after running profiler trace and running the results by db engine tuning advisor, it proposed that I create the following index (which is the same index I have but with the key columns reversed):

```
create nonclusteredindex [index2] on [dbo].[tb_StatusLog]
(
statusID asc, 
requestID asc
)
include ([startTime])
```

Now, when running `fn_getTable`, the execution plan uses `index2` instead of `index1` and the performance improved.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have an equality predicate on `where statusID=2`.

With the reversed order it is able to seek into exactly the rows matching the status and these can then feed into a stream aggregate to do the grouping.

Your original index supports the `group by requestID, statusID` but not the `WHERE` - meaning the whole index will need to be scanned and only rows matching the `statusID=2` retained.

Comment: which index does the `group by` use then?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat simplified, but you can think of a composite index as if rows are ordered first by the first column, second by the second column and so forth. Your first example would be:

```
requestID     statusID
----------------------
-> A             1
|  A             2
v  A             3
   B             1
   B             2
x  B             4
```

To find rows with statusId=2 there is no way to tell where to start, the whole index has to be scanned. Compare with:

```
statusID      requestID
----------------------
   1             A
   1             B
-> 2             A
v  2             B
x  3             A
   4             B
```

The DBMS can start with (2,A), read another entry (2,B) and be done with it.